# How to customize the $ionicPopup to show the details?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

In my Ionic project (Ionic + AngularJS), I need to use the `$ionicPopup` kind of box to show the full details of the particular product when the user clicks on that product name. But, I was trying to customizing the popup, I couldn't. Even, I tried with `templateUrl : templates/example.html`. But, I didn't get the expected results.

I need to show the product's details with a width of 75% and a height of 75%. Or is there any other way to display the details with the same kind of effect `$ionicPopup` do. Please, help me out.

Comment: For customising I use css . It is interesting to know different methods to solve this problem

Comment: How? Could u explain this?

Comment: As whole page is HTML, so you can add css to pop up box. If you inspect element of the pop up box then you will see different classes like popup and popup head. Now you just need to add specific style for each classes as per  you need. Make those styles as Important for overriding original styles.

Comment: for showing the details, Do i have to use template or templateUrl? Because, now I am using as separate html page and I use templateUrl. But, I am not retrieving the data from the controller to my popup.

Comment: If you getting that html tags you can manage css and if problem is solved by model then don't use css because this may change other integration.